# sql trigger counts modification

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I would like to Write a trigger that  after each modification of the number of records in the
tables (Tb1, Tb2, Tb3) by identifying the number of records in each of the
three tables and using a sequence (id_sequence) which increments by a jump of two.

Can't figure out how to do the trigger

```
CREATE TABLE tp1_pastille
(
 id_pastille  int NOT NULL,
 model        varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 description  varchar(50) NULL,
 numero_serie int NOT NULL,
 prix         double precision NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CK_pastille CHECK (prix >= 0),
 CONSTRAINT PK_pastille PRIMARY KEY ( id_pastille )


CREATE TABLE tp1_compte
(
 id_compte          int NOT NULL,
 date_achat         date NOT NULL,
 id_pastille        int NOT NULL,
 id_usager          int NOT NULL,
 probabilite_malade double precision NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_compte PRIMARY KEY ( id_compte ),
 CONSTRAINT UQ_compte_id_pastille UNIQUE ( id_pastille ),
 CONSTRAINT UQ_compte_id_usager UNIQUE ( id_usager ),
 CONSTRAINT FK_compte_id_pastille FOREIGN KEY ( id_pastille ) REFERENCES tp1_pastille ( id_pastille ),
 CONSTRAINT FK_compte_id_usager FOREIGN KEY ( id_usager ) REFERENCES tp1_usager ( id_usager )
);
CREATE TABLE tp1_transaction
(
 id_transaction   int NOT NULL,
 id_pastille_1    int NOT NULL,
 id_pastille_2    int NOT NULL,
 "date"           timestamp NOT NULL,
 puissance_signal double precision NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_transaction PRIMARY KEY ( id_transaction, id_pastille_1, id_pastille_2 ),
 CONSTRAINT FK_transaction_id_pastille_1 FOREIGN KEY ( id_pastille_1 ) REFERENCES tp1_pastille ( id_pastille ),
 CONSTRAINT FK_transaction_id_pastille_2 FOREIGN KEY ( id_pastille_2 ) REFERENCES tp1_pastille ( id_pastille )
);
```

Comment: This going to need a complete example of what you want to do, as your current explanation is to incomplete to come to any answer.

Comment: I added the table. In general I want to be able to create a trigger that allows me that after each modification that has been made on one of those 3 tables give a sequence that increment by +2

Comment: Still not understanding what you want. Add some pseudo code to the question that illustrates the logic of what you want to do.